# Call to SQL Server stored procedure failing in certain cases

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am struggling to understand why a certain stored procedure has stopped working in a few of my databases, but not in others. I am hoping that someone can help me resolve this issue.

**Introduction**

I inherited an existing C# application that connects to a choice of SQL Server databases depending on the culture parameter supplied to the program. Example: Passing "**en-CA**" causes the program to connect to the database with English-Canada content. Passing "**fr-CA**" causes the program to connect to the database with French-Canada content. The databases are derived from a common root database. The databases are essentially identical except for the contents of many of the **NVARCHAR** fields. (*This variety of databases is used solely during development for testing various cultures.*)

Both databases use the following collation: **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**

**Issue**

I am not sure when this issue started, but the current situation is that if I call a certain stored procedure from the **fr-CA** database, then it is not executed at all. (*I will explain this in more detail.*) No error code is returned to the program. the program acts as if no record was found.

However, if I call the same stored procedure from the **en-CA** database, then it functions as expected and a record is returned to the program.

**Attempted Steps**

If I run the stored procedure from SSMS, then it executes properly.

[image: Successful execution of stored procedure.]

I have attempted copying the definition of the stored procedure from the database where it is executing properly to the database where it is not executing properly. This did not resolve the issue.

I did try debugging with the SQL Profiler. When I ran the stored procedure against both databases, I see an entry in the trace. I do not see any errors listed. I will admit that I am a newbie when it comes to using the Profiler.

When I say that the stored procedure is not being executed, I base this on the following test. I created a debug table with a couple of fields:

```
create table DEBUG
(
    Id INTEGER,
    Line NVARCHAR(100)
);
```

At the top of the stored procedure, in both databases, I inserted as the very first line the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DEBUG VALUES (1, 'Top of Atms_Get_Tray_Infos');
```

When my code calls the stored procedure, I expect to see a line in the **DEBUG** table.

If I run the program against the **en-CA** database, I do see the expected line:

[image: Expected debug line.]

If I empty the **DEBUG** table and then run the program against the **fr-CA** database, the **DEBUG** table remains empty. This fact leads me to believe that the stored procedure is not being executed.

**Database details**

Here is the definition of the stored procedure with the debug line:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Atms_Get_Tray_Infos]
    @TrayNo AS NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- DEBUG
    INSERT INTO dbo.DEBUG VALUES (1, 'Top of Atms_Get_Tray_Infos');

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT  HTRAY.SEQ_HIST_PLATEAU AS TRAYNO,
                HTRAY.DATE_EXPIRATION_DATE AS EXPIRY,
                HTRAY.DATE_UTILISATION_DATE AS DATEUSED,
                HTRAY.LADATE_LAVAGE AS WASHDATE,
                HSTE.SEQ_CODE_QUAL_STERIL AS QLTYCODE,
                HSTE.NO_CHARGE AS CHGNO,
                HSTE.TEST_BIO_BON AS BIOTEST,
                FRML.CODE AS FORMULACODE,
                TRAY.NO_TYPE_PLATEAU AS TRAYCODE,
                TRAY.DESCRIPTION_S,
                TRAY.EstUrgent AS URGENT
        FROM dbo.HIST_PLAT HTRAY
        LEFT JOIN dbo.HIST_CHARG_STE HSTE ON HTRAY.LAST_SEQ_HIST_CHARGE_STERIL = HSTE.SEQ_HIST_CHARGE_STERIL
        INNER JOIN dbo.PLATEAUX TRAY ON TRAY.SEQ_PLATEAU = HTRAY.NO_SEQ_PLATEAU
        INNER JOIN dbo.FORMULE FRML ON HSTE.SEQ_FORMULE = FRML.SEQ_FORMULE
        WHERE HTRAY.SEQ_HIST_PLATEAU = @TrayNo
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH
END
```

I appreciate any bit of assistance that will lead me to a resolution of this issue. Thanks!

Comment: If you see an entry in the trace of the Profiler, then procedure **is** executed. It may be executed in a scope of a transaction, which later rolls back. This could explain why you don't see a row inserted into `dbo.DEBUG`.

Comment: how do you call the procedure exactly? i mean if in your code you have something like `sqlCmd.CommandName="[dbo].[Atms_Get_Tray_Infos]";` or `sqlCmd.CommandName="[Atms_Get_Tray_Infos]";` or anything else (maybe dynamic sql).

Comment: @Vladimir, I do not see any mechanism that would call the stored procedure in a transaction. Also, would this explain why the stored procedure works as expected on certain database, but not others?

Comment: @RayGoudie, it is hard to say anything specific. It seems that you confirmed that there is some problem with your C# code as you said in your answer. So, you know where to look further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paolo's comment, above, caused me to investigate the actual C# code that calls the stored procedure.

The code is convoluted for the sake of being convoluted, in my opinion.
There is a method is some class that handles all calls to stored procedures. I replaced that code with this basic code:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("ReturnDs");
using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(theConnectStg))
{
    using (var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(theStoreProcName, connection))
    {
        using (var dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (theParameterList != null)
            {
                foreach (String str1 in theParameterList.ToArray())
                {
                    String parameterName = str1.Substring(0, str1.IndexOf(":"));
                    String str2 = str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf(":") + 1);
                    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameterName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 128));
                    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[parameterName].Value = (object)str2;
                }
            }
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }
    }
}
return dataSet;
```

To satisfy your curiosity, the **theParameterList** parameter is an array of parameters, each in the form "**@variable:value**". I'm not a fan, but I am stuck with the existing code for now.

So, why did the previous code fail for certain databases? I still do not know. I am curious, but I do not wish to spend any more time on this issue. My brain is tired.

Thanks for the clue, Paolo!